# Converting a text file to Map<String, List<String>> using lambda

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert the following text input file:

```
A=groupA1
A=groupA2
A=groupA3
B=groupB1
B=groupB2
```

into `Map<String, List<String>>` by splitting each line on `"="`

So far I manged to get this sort of output:

```
KEY: A
VALUE: A=groupA1
VALUE: A=groupA2
VALUE: A=groupA3
KEY: B
VALUE: B=groupB1
VALUE: B=groupB2
```

using such code:

```
File reqFile = new File("test.config");

try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(reqFile.toPath())) {
    Map<String, List<String>> conf = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("=")[0]));
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: conf.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("KEY: " + entry.getKey());
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println("VALUE: " + value);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How to tweak the above lambda to get something like this:

```
KEY: A
VALUE: groupA1
VALUE: groupA2
VALUE: groupA3
KEY: B
VALUE: groupB1
VALUE: groupB2
```

Comment: much like regular expressions, once you decide to solve a problem with lambdas now you have two problems ( if you do not 100% comprehend what you are doing and why you are doing it that way ). Regular non-lambda solution would be far more efficient and more importantly **readable** and **maintainable**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Map and collect:

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = lines.stream()
    .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("=")))
    .collect(HashMap::new,
            (map, item) -> map.computeIfAbsent(item.get(0), k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item.get(1)),
            HashMap::putAll);
```

Or map and group by:

```
Map<String, List<String>> res = lines.stream()
        .map(s -> Arrays.asList(s.split("=")))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.get(0), Collectors.mapping(v->v.get(1), Collectors.toList())));
```

1. [`Stream.collect` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)

Comment: No problem. Mapping solves problem with splitting items two times. I have also added a version with grouping by collectors. If you think it is helpful for you, please, upvote it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Collectors.mapping` while `groupingBy`, for more information look at this [doc-with-example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)

```
Map<String, List<String>> conf = stream.    
   collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("=")[0], Collectors.mapping(v->v.split("=")[1], Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(conf); //{A=[groupA1, groupA2, groupA3], B=[groupB1, groupB2]}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!

```Map<String, List<String>> conf = stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.split("=")[0], Collectors.mapping(v->v.split("=")[1], Collectors.toList())));```

and the output:

```KEY: A
VALUE: groupA1
VALUE: groupA2
VALUE: groupA3
KEY: B
VALUE: groupB1
VALUE: groupB2```

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to using a third-party library, the following will work using [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
ListMultimap<String, String> strings = stream
        .map(s -> s.split("="))
        .collect(Collectors2.toListMultimap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));
```

[`Collectors2.toListMultimap`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#toListMultimap-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function-) takes a `Function` to calculate the key and a separate `Function` to calculate the value.  The [`ListMultimap<K, V>`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/multimap/list/ListMultimap.html) type is equivalent to `Map<K, List<V>>`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.